# Errors extracting some characters from PDF files using Python

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, pypdf

I'm trying to extract some texts from PDF files using PyPDF2, but I'm encountering some problems. Here is my code and a pdf example file (with correct characters).
You can download the pdf file here: https://github.com/giadabart/sharedfiles/blob/main/document-page259.pdf

```
def extractTextFromPdf(filename, ignore_newline=False):
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader as pfr 
    reader = pfr(filename) 
    content = '' # encoding = 'UTF8'
    for p in reader.pages:
        content += p.extractText() 
    if ignore_newline:
        content = content.replace('\n', '')
    return content
estrazione_prova = extractTextFromPdf('input/document-page259.pdf')
estrazione_prova
```

The output I get is:

```
'APPENDICEB.APPENDICECARTOGRAFICA EICONOGRAFICA\nTabella B.1\nSoggetto\nPianta degliortia OvestdelBattistero.\nAutore\nRanieriCorsi\nData\nNondatato\nTe c n i c a\n-\nDimensioni\n-\nIscrizioni\nPianta dellÕOrto attenentealla VenerabilOpera delDuomo diPisa\ndetto LÕOrto da SanGiovanni.\nCollo cazione\nPisa,Opera della PrimazialePisana,Archivio.\nDescrizione\nNeldisegno sono rappresentatigliorticoltivatiadOvestdelBat-\ntistero,la Casa dellÕOrtolano eilmuro divisorio checosteggiava\nla Porta ovestdelmonumento.Adovesttalepropriet‹ conÞnava\nconunÕaltra porzionediterreno dipropriet‹ della Dogana diPisa,\ncomeattesta lÕiscrizionelungo ilmarginesinistro deldisegno.\nNote\n-\nBibliograÞa\n-\n250\n'
```

What is wrong with the output is:

- the apostrophe which is read as "Õ";
- "à" becoming "‹";
- syllable "fi" turning into the greek letter "Þ";
- (sometimes) misplaced spaces between two or more consecutive words.
  Example: "Pianta degliortia OvestdelBattistero." should be "Pianta degli orti a Ovest del Battistero.

If I copy and paste the text from the pdf (document-page259.pdf) to a "LibreOffice Writer" file to understand if there is any problem with the original pdf, each character matches the original one. So, I guess there isn't any particular error in the pdf.

I also tried to copy and paste the text from the pdf (document-page259.pdf) to a "LibreOffice Calc" and it sets Unicode (UTF-16) as the character set. By doing so, I get the correct match between the original pdf text and the copied one.

Finally, I tried the following code to understand something about encoding, but it doesn't help to solve the problem.

```
estrazione_prova = extractTextFromPdf('input/document-page259.pdf')
x = estrazione_prova.encode()
print(x)
```

The output is:

```
b'APPENDICEB.APPENDICECARTOGRAFICA EICONOGRAFICA\nTabella B.1\nSoggetto\nPianta degliortia OvestdelBattistero.\nAutore\nRanieriCorsi\nData\nNondatato\nTe c n i c a\n-\nDimensioni\n-\nIscrizioni\nPianta dell\xc3\x95Orto attenentealla VenerabilOpera delDuomo diPisa\ndetto L\xc3\x95Orto da SanGiovanni.\nCollo cazione\nPisa,Opera della PrimazialePisana,Archivio.\nDescrizione\nNeldisegno sono rappresentatigliorticoltivatiadOvestdelBat-\ntistero,la Casa dell\xc3\x95Ortolano eilmuro divisorio checosteggiava\nla Porta ovestdelmonumento.Adovesttalepropriet\xe2\x80\xb9 con\xc3\x9enava\nconun\xc3\x95altra porzionediterreno dipropriet\xe2\x80\xb9 della Dogana diPisa,\ncomeattesta l\xc3\x95iscrizionelungo ilmarginesinistro deldisegno.\nNote\n-\nBibliogra\xc3\x9ea\n-\n250\n'
```

Please, could anyone give me an idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: I've tried running your program and everything works. I'm on a windows machine using vscode. Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes @KapJ1coH, I'm on a windows machine and I'm using Jupyter to run the code. Don't you get "Õ" in place of the apostrophe or "<" in place of "à" and so on?

Comment: Nope, the output is right. I get the apostrophes and so on. Try maybe running it in the console.

Comment: Your code works in Windows 21H1 [Version 10.0.19043.2006], PyPDF2 2.10.8, Python 3.10.2 (both from `cmd.exe` or `Terminal` app).